# Toggling the console opened and closed in a Python program

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, console, python-3.5

I have a program I am writing in Python 3.5 in which I like to toggle the console window opened and closed. This program is based entirely in tkinter but I would like the user of my program, which is a [battleship game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) by the way, to be able to open the console window if he/she wishes to look at debug information, etcetera.

Is it possible to do this and how?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should also note I would like the console window to be still functioning while it is not open. That is, I would like text that I print to it to still be "showing up" on the console. With that said, I suppose what I'm really looking for is a way to just *hide* the console; meaning it's still there functioning, just not visible.

Comment: Tkinter doesn't work that way. Uncaught errors will send a traceback to the terminal, but you can't interact with it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Darn, that's unfortunate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can make a tkinter-based 'pseudoconsole': a Toplevel with a Text widget or a subclass thereof.  You can redirect stdout and stderr to the pseudoconsole by creating classes with write methods that redirect output to the Text instance.  The two instances of the class can color the the two streams differently. This is how user program output ends up in, for instance, IDLE's Shell window.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes I considered this, but It's not a huge deal, I was mainly just interested to see if I could do it. Thank you though, I may make one just for fun.